# Cambiar enums en migracion rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un problema al tener que agregar un nuevo tipo de notificacion a un conjunto ya agregadas por migracion, el codigo es el sigiente:

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def up
execute <<-DDL
    CREATE TYPE notifications_types AS ENUM (
      'pending_subscription', 'approved_subscription', 'rejected_subscription', 'pending_evaluation', 'feedback_ready', 'course_capacity', 'student_feedback_ready'
    );
  DDL

create_table :notifications do |t|
  t.column :notification_type, :notifications_types
  t.integer :user_id
  t.boolean :read
  t.integer :course_id
  t.integer :stage_id
  t.integer :exercise_id
  t.integer :answer_id
  t.integer :feedback_id
  t.json  :data

  t.timestamps
end
end

def down
drop_table :notifications
execute "DROP type notifications_types;"
 end
end
```

y lo que requiero es agregar un nuevo tipo de notificacion al conjunto que esta arriba en enum pero al agregar y crear la migracion esta no ocurre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo que muestres como estás agregando el nuevo tipo, tampoco cual DB Engine estás usando, pero la manera de hacerlo según la [documentación de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) es con:

```
ALTER TYPE notifications_types ADD VALUE tu_nuevo_tipo;
```

Comment: Esa era gracias man!